# SwaggerUI Asp.Net Core - How to ref .json files

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui

How would you add a swagger.json file to SwaggerUI? So far I only was able to generate one and it automatically "refs" itself in the web app and is callable from /swagger/v1/swagger.json, the only help I was able to find was about URL routing but how does swagger find the specifications in your project?

I would also be able to add multiple .json files to SwaggerUI, the documentation says to do this way

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
             {
               c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "SwaggerDemo v1");
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "SwaggerDemo v2");
             });
```

But this is only routing where does swagger find this JSON file?

Isn't there a way to do something like this?

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(c => c.AddSpec("./Swagger/swagger1.json"));
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you CAN'T, if you want to ref a local .json spec you have to root it.

In a controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetSwaggerSpec()
        {
            var path = Path.GetFullPath(<SWAGGER.JSON>);
            StreamReader stream = System.IO.File.OpenText(path);
            return stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

In Startup.cs:

```
app.UseSwaggerUi3(c => c.SwaggerRoutes.Add(new SwaggerUi3Route("All", "/api/default")));
```